# document.getElementById always return empty where it shouldn't

Tags: javascript

Application is using laravel 5.8,
and what i'm trying to do is to get the selected value,
the selection is generated using select2.

What is the proper way to extract the selected value? Since i always get empty for the value.

The view :

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>
  Select Industry
 </label>
<select name="industryid" id="industryid" class="findIndustry js-example-responsive" style="width: 100%">
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.findIndustry').select2({
minimumResultsForSearch: 3,
ajax: {
 url: '/cases/find_industry',
dataType: 'json',
delay: 250,
headers : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
processResults: function(industry) {
return {
results: $.map(industry, function(industry) {
return {
text: industry.sra_industry+' - '+industry.sra_description,                                         id: industry.sra_industry                                           }                                       })
};
},
                                        });
</script>
</div>
```

Where i try to get the selected value :

```
var one = document.getElementById("industryid");

var two = document.getElementById("industryid").value;

// i trigger from some button
function reply_click()
{
console.log(one);
console.log(two);
}

console.log(one) is responding, but (two) always empty. 
result log below..

console.log(one) :

<select name="industryid" id="industryid" class="findIndustry js-example-responsive select2-hidden-accessible" style="width: 100%" data-select2-id="industryid" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">`enter code here`
<option value="EFEK" data-select2-id="19">EFEK - Sector Company</option><
/select>

console.log(two) - empty :


///////////////////////
```

Based on the sample above, i want to get the selected value above -> option value = "EFEK" and store it inside the var two.

Thanks

Comment: You need to perform `var two = document.getElementById("industryid").value;` inside `reply_click` function

Comment: You're running that code before `.select2()` has loaded the options, so when you read `.value`, they don't exist yet.

Comment: Fix! thanks for the insight and explanation everybody. somehow i didn't think of that, will need to learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines run **immediately** when the script is executed:

```
var one = document.getElementById("industryid");

var two = document.getElementById("industryid").value;
```

That means that if the element doesn't exist (yet), you'll get `null` for `one` and the second line will fail. But if the element exists (for instance, if the `script` is after the `select` in the HTML), you'll get the element in `one` and `""` in `two`, because nothing is selected in the select.

You want to get the value **later**, when processing the click. And since `getElementById` is really, really fast, there's no reason not to do that then, too:

```
function reply_click()
{
    console.log(document.getElementById("industryid").value);
}
```